# Deploy DB with FluentMigrator

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-migrations, fluent-migrator

How to create first deployment DB with FluentMigrator to my local SQL2014? I have project in .NET 4.6.1.
I expect command like Update-Database, but no. What is the right way?

Answer (score 0):

As I know there's tree ways to run migrations in FluentMigrator:

1. You can do it using [.net fm tool](https://fluentmigrator.github.io/articles/runners/dotnet-fm.html)
2. You can use [Migrate.exe](https://fluentmigrator.github.io/articles/runners/runner-console.html)
3. Write your [own code to do it](https://fluentmigrator.github.io/articles/quickstart.html?tabs=runner-in-process)

Comment: Thank you, but it seems as .NET CORE future, however I have .NET Framework site, therefore I have no 1 and 2 future. 3-rd way maybe is possible, yes.

Comment: Well, migrate.exe will work for .net framework too - in last project we had it since ages before switched to .net core. Not sure about fm tool, but why not? It's just library with migrations and database. Nothing is .net core depended